# _Scary->**_Myhead** was 0xDDDDDDDD VC++ Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

I got this error when debugging in VC++: _Scary->**_Myhead** was 0xDDDDDDDD. I would like to know what this error means, possible sources, and possible solutions. I think it may have something to do with std::map usage, but I'm not sure. For reference, the debugger leads me to a file called "xtree". Unfortunately, I have no idea how to reproduce this because it is a big project and I do not know why this error is occuring.

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` means freed heap memory. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: It means you have a bug in your code. You will have to find the bug, and fix it.

Comment: My guess (not having any code at all) is you have a class that violates the rule of 3 / 5 / 0.

Comment: ***the debugger leads me to a file called "xtree"*** Change the "Stack Frame" combobox on the debug toolbar to your code to see what line of your code caused this.

Comment: @drescherjm Where is this setting?

Comment: Should be on the Visual Studio toolbar somewhere at the top of the screen.